# LaTeX: using (not creating) a command with 2 optional arguments

Tags: formatting, arguments, latex, enumerate

I'm trying to get an enumeration with my own specific formatting in two different ways (homework assignment to copy something someone else made):

-the numbers look like (1), (2), (3), etc.

-there is no spacing before or after the enumeration or between its items

I can get each of those two things at a time after loading the enumitem package with shortlabels with the following different snippets of code, respectively:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(1)]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
\end{enumerate}
```

The former makes the numbers be (1), (2), etc. and the latter removes spacing. However, I can't do both at once without LaTeX refusing to compile it because it can't see the items afterwards:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(1)][nolistsep]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
\end{enumerate}
```

I'm sure there's a proper syntax to use 2 different square-bracket arguments at once, but I can't find it, because Googling this issue only finds people trying to *create* commands with more than one argument.

EDIT: Nevermind. I immediately figured it out. I just needed a comma:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(1), nolistsep]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
\end{enumerate}
```

I'm gonna leave this here for Google to find, because it's dumb how much of a sweet spot this issue is in, between being hard to find in a manual or examples and hard to find from Googling.

Comment: You should add the solution you found as an answer, and accept this answer (after grace period of 2 days from thread creation) to close the question.

Comment: Are you using the [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) or [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package(s)?

Comment: @Werner enumitem with shortlabels

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I immediately figured it out. I just needed a comma:

```
\begin{enumerate}[(1), nolistsep]
  \item item 1
  \item item 2
\end{enumerate}
```

I'm gonna leave this here for Google to find, because it's dumb how much of a sweet spot this issue is in, between being hard to find in a manual or examples and hard to find from Googling.